# Entity Framework migrations stopped detecting the POCO updates

Tags: entity-framework, migration, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Entity Framework and Entity Framework migrations to implement solution using code-first and automatic migrations.

It used to work great but suddenly it stopped detecting the updates I make to my POCO. Now when I add a new property (very simple properties like age or email) and execute the `Update-Database`, nothing happens, and it gives me this:

> Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view SQL commands being executed during migration.
>   Found 0 pending explicit migrations: [].
>   Adding seed data (if Seed method overridden in Migrations Settings class).

and nothing gets updated!

Has anyone any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is the AutomaticMigrationsEnabled flag still set?

Comment: Does it detect changes if you run Add-Migration?

Comment: Automatic Migration is set to True, i didn't check the add-migration, but now i had to uninstall entity-framework migration and install it again to fix it, and its working now so right now i cant tell, but if it happened again i would check add-Migration

Comment: Yeah i've had some issues where I've had to reinstall it too, I wondered if it was because I was using the new NuGet 1.6 method of not storing packages in source control.

Comment: What happens if you backup your database and tries to revert all migrations and after that runs Update-Database?

Comment: now i got the problem again !, its so weird cause it happens randomly, @LadislavMrnka i will try your suggestion now.....

Comment: @LadislavMrnka trying your suggestion didn`t fix the problem, i "Update-Database -TargetMigration:0 -force" then "Update-Database"
and still new properties doesnt get detected :(

Comment: but here is how i fixed it with a workaround
I uninstalled the Migration Package and installed it again, then update-database , it fixed it

Comment: Sounds like they may have fixed this issue in one of the minor NuGet patches, either way you should probably add your solution as an answer and close this question.

Comment: @Betty what i said is a workaround not a solution, i would rather not approve this as an answer, i have the latest patch of NuGet and i still get this issue from time to time.

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you do turn the output window to Diagnostic? [Instructions how to turn on][1]


  [1]: http://saraford.net/2008/10/07/did-you-know-you-can-configure-the-msbuild-verbosity-in-the-output-window-329/

Comment: I've been having the same problem but with model-first. Modified my model and nothing was updated to the database... now that is mentioned, I am the only one in my team with NuGet... will get back to you

Answer (score 2):

This may be in two reasons:

1. There is some other DbContext in code, that's why automatic migrations could not decide, which context to use.
2. There is some new change, which loops a comparison of schema and code model, so EF simply could not find the difference.

In general, automatic migrations are simple and fast to implement, but it is not secured to use them. On some stage, such migrations could make a fail.

Several years ago, I have developed tiny ORM based on Linq2SQL, [AcroDB Library](https://github.com/acropolium/AcroDB), and it was using automigrations of [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/). Almost same as EF migrations can do now. It was perfect on small projects and small amount of data to process or change, but when project has grow into 15+ tables, it became a nightmare. That's why MS has announced [Code-driven migrations](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2012/02/15/using-entity-framework-4-3-database-migration-for-any-project.aspx) lately. They are more secured and better for the project. Also, you can take a look to [Migrator.Net](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) (it is a bit better than EF, by this time).